# how to pass 2 dimensional array to as a intent in the android

Tags: android, android-intent, multidimensional-array

I want to pass the following  array to my `receiver` class in the same format and fetch it in same format i.e the array should maintain its structure.

```
 curDts= new String[][] {{"1","2","3"}, {}, {"4","5","6"}};
```

Following is what I have tried so far,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            for(int i = 0; i<curDts.length ; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<curDts[i].length; j++){
                    intent.putExtra("date"+i,"'"+curDts[i][j]+"',");
                    Log.v("sending","'"+curDts[i][j]+"',");
                }
            }

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++){    
        Log.v("",""+arg1.getExtras().getString("date"+i));
        }
```

Comment: `"date"+i` will be overwritten `curDts[i].length` times.

Comment: Why not put the whole array as a Serializable object?

Comment: don't know if I understand correctly, but you just want to pass the array to your receiver , have you tried to send it in the intent like intent.putExtra(key,SERIALIZABLE); and in the receiver get it lile intent.getSerializable(KEY); ??

Answer (score 2):

String[] are serializable objects as well as String[][] that means you can simply use the ready method in the intent `intent.putExtra(key,serializableObject)` , and on your receiver side you could say `intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY);`

if that what you was looking for.

**Edited**

To pass your data do something like :

```
    Object[] objArr = new Object[]{ new String[]{"2"} ,new String[]{"5"}};
    intent.putExtra("dates", objArr);
```

and to retreive them :

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new  BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Object[] obj = (Object[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("dates");
    if(obj != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            String[] object = (String[])obj[i];
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "OBJ : " + object[0]);
        }
    }

    }
};
```

Comment: can u plz elaborate this with an example

Comment: @user2750762 I have added sample receiver to show how to get your array[][]

Comment: I guess it will throw `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]`.

Comment: yes it is throwing me class cast exception                                i am doing this in my main activity class intent.putExtra("dates",curDts); and on reciving end  String[][] myArray = (String[][]) arg1.getSerializableExtra("dates");

Answer (score 1):

You Can simply do like this:
in the first class:

```
String[][] bidderList; 
Intent intent = new Intent(class1.this, class2.class);
intent.putExtra("bidderList",bidderList);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then in the second class where you want to receive the 2d array do like this:

```
String[][] bidderList;
bidderList =(String[][]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("bidderList");
```

And that is all :>, you will need to use for loop to access the String[][] array elements

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to encode each String array within the larger array of arrays into a String, and pass a String array through the Intent. This String array can be decoded by the Activity receiving the Intent.

I wrote a class that can encode/decode a String array, which can be found here: https://gist.github.com/liangricha/10759438.

Alternatively, you can look into Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass integers, and you can pass `String[]`, so:

```
int i = 0;
intent.putExtra("size", curDts.length);
for (String[] value : curDts) {
    intent.putExtra("item"+ i++, value);
}
```

To retrieve it:

```
int size = intent.getIntExtra("size", 0);
String[][] curDts = new String[][size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    curDts[i] = intent.getStringArrayExtras('item" + i);
}
```

Comment: 07-12 19:00:14.512: V/accessing(18012): [Ljava.lang.String;@426de358
showing me this error

Comment: this is not an error, this is a log. I don't know what you are trying to log, but this look like a String[], so it seems ok so far..

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...
Note : try to use ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> insted of two dimensional which can be easy Serializable.


**FirstActivty**
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
        first.add("1");
        first.add("2");
        first.add("3");

        ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
        second.add("4");
        second.add("5");
        second.add("6");

        ArrayList<String> third = new ArrayList<String>();
        third.add("7");
        third.add("8");
        third.add("9");

        list.add(first);
        list.add(second);
        list.add(third);
        Intent intent =new Intent(this,MyActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("SerializableList",list);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

**SecondActivity**
public class MyActivity2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("SerializableList");

        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            ArrayList<String> row = list.get(i);
            for (int j=0;j<row.size();j++){
                System.out.println("ParentIndex >> ChildIndex >> Value "+i+" >> "+j+" >> "+row.get(j));
            }
        }
    }

}
```